# Better to use low ESR or high ESR caps?

Tags: capacitor, repair, theory

I'm replacing the old filter capacitors on Marshall guitar amp and I was wondering if I should use low/non-low ESR caps for this.

As my understanding is (which is neither deep nor correct probably) that with higher frequency you should use lower ESR. So if I operate on 230V/50Hz system, that means low frequency thus high ESR capacitor would be preferable?

Here's the schematics: https://www.thetubestore.com/lib/thetubestore/schematics/Marshall/Marshall-Valvestate80-80W-8080-8100-8412-Schematic.pdf

More specifically two 2200uF 50V and two 1000uf 16V capacitors.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It depends. Why can't you use the _correct_ caps as specified by the manufacturer?

Comment: I'm guessing they're just general-purpose types. Replace with comparable ratings. There's a chance you can identify the type/family and find a datasheet or direct sub / cross-reference.

Comment: You must think the load is “high” frequency also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those electrolytic capacitors are part of the AC power supply rather than the amp itself. Lower ESR is better, although it likely will not matter much. I would pick high quality, name brand capacitors regardless. Better than needed will not hurt if you are unsure.

In general lower ESR makes the capacitor better at filtering ripple in a low impedance circuit. It's not directly related to frequency.